# Where are log files for Tridion LDAP configuration

Tags: configuration, ldap

I have a Tridion 2013 installation that I'm configuring for LDAP. I've followed the steps for LDAP configuration in the documentation. When I try to access the Tridion CME, I'm prompted for authentication. I enter credentials that I know are valid, but the authentication window appears again (as though the credentials never got authenticated)

Where would I find log files that could tell me if there's an error with the authentication?

Comment: The easiest way I found to debug LDAP issues is network sniffing tools... finding out exactly what is sent to the LDAP server (and what comes back) usually helps a lot. Something like http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the following logs to see what's happening:

1. The Tridion Event Log
2. The Windows security log
3. Any IIS logging ( event log and the website logging )

If nothing is logged, use an LDAP sniffer or Fiddler to see what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect they are in the SDL Tridion Content Manager 'Snap-In' / SDL Tridion event log on the CM machine.  Have you tried looking in there?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your impersonation user is set up correctly, the most important authentication that takes place is the bind to the LDAP server. Correspondingly, the most important logs to look in are those of the LDAP server itself. Where these are to be found depends on which LDAP  server you are using, but it shouldn't be too hard to find out where they are. (Of course, depending on the environment you are operating in, you might need to work with the relevant systems administrator.)